# Karma or TypeScript compiler told me Property 'padStart' does not exist on type 'String'

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have a Angular 7 project with with lib=es2015 and target=es2015, and Angular-CLI compiling and the app running are very much OK. However, when running unit tests with `ng test`, Karma or TypeScript compiler told me Property 'padStart' does not exist on type 'String'

```
27 03 2019 10:40:57.424:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.0.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
27 03 2019 10:40:57.424:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
27 03 2019 10:40:57.429:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
ERROR in node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/lib/utils/utils.common.ts(300,24): error TS2339: Property 'padStart' does not exist on type 'String'.
node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/lib/utils/utils.common.ts(301,26): error TS2339: Property 'padStart' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

When checking the offending codes as indicated in the error message:

```js
export function padStart(
  currentString: string,
  targetLength: number,
  padString: string = " "
): string {
  if (String.prototype.padStart) {
    return currentString.padStart(targetLength, padString);
  }
...
```

I find that the last 2 lines of codes are looking perfectly fine to me, since I understand that padStart is defined in es2017, so the programmers of the lib had crafted those. If in tsconfig.json I have lib=es2017 and target=es2015, the compiling of ng test is fine.

I like to find out the cause of the problem, and the suspects are: Type Script compiler, Karma, Angular compiler, or the offending codes. Which one do you think?

Comment: I believe that karma will use a different tsconfig out of the box ... can you try updating src/app/tsconfig.test.json?

Comment: Does that error show when you run ng build?

Comment: @Explosion Pills, while Angular.json does point to tsconfig.test.json which does not define lib and target, I believe karma also use tsconfig.json which is apparently shared by both app and spec, since changing tsconfig.json for lib and target does fix the problem. However, I think the offending codes is fine in all versions of JavaScript engine semantically. Do you think so? I just like to find out the cause of the problem, and the suspects are: TS compiler, Karma, Angular compiler, or the offending codes. Which one do you think?

Answer (score 0):

> If in tsconfig.json I have lib=es2017 and target=es2015, the compiling of ng test is fine

This is the correct fix. `padStart` only came with `ES2017` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

[image]

Comment: I am aware of this. However, the offending code looks fine in all versions of JavaScript. Do you think so? I like to find out the cause of the problem, and the suspects are: Type Script compiler, Karma, Angular compiler, or the offending codes. Which one do you think? since compiling with `ng build --base-href --aot` has no problem. My guess is that AOT compiling is smarter through checking the detection code, while TS compiler used by Karma is not so smart. However, I am not sure.

Comment: ` However, the offending code looks fine in all versions of JavaScript` No. It is not fine in anything before ES2017 e.g. ES2016. That said, it can be polyfiled 